# Image Manipulation using javascript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing

I'm creating a image editor and wanted to use any good image manipulation js library. I'm already using CAMANJS but the problem is that I'm using slidder for adjusting image like - sharpness and contrast.
It works like a charm but I want to render the adjusted image on the go, as the slidder moves not when user leaves sliider(ie - onMouseUp - unlike the CamanJs example: http://camanjs.com/examples/).

Is it possible to do in Camanjs or can someone suggest some library that does this on the fly(ie- as the slidder moves).

Comment: There will always be some cost involved in terms of time because its an image, it takes time to render. Even you make it on the fly you will still experience the delay in rendering the image.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh I totally understand that rendering image takes time but there are editor which are doing this, eg: https://www.befunky.com/create/photo-editor/ .  Just wanted to know what approach they might be following so they are able to do that so quickly.

Comment: You are right, tried that site, the effects are pretty smooth and on the fly.